# Solo Cluster Mining

Tags: linux, solo-mining

My company has a ~270 node cluster we're thinking of turning into a solo mining operation during downtime. Can anyone direct me to a comprehensive tutorial on how to set this up?

Comment: Most likely this will cost you more in electricity than you'll earn. GPU and CPU mining both has gone the way of the dodo, due to the enhanced performance of ASICs. Definitely check the costs before going ahead!

Comment: Cluster nodes sounds like cpu, no high performance gpu. Either way, you won't mine anything with that. It wasn't worth it in 2013 with a high end gpu. Dodo is the right term.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an estimate on how many TH/s this cluster can do? I would advise against solo mining unless you can manage to comprise at least 0.1% of the network hash rate, which currently (August 2015) would be about 50TH/s.

Even with pooled mining, it's probably a waste of time.

It may be profitable to mine some altcoin, but I am not familiar with all of them, and you have not mentioned any specs for your cluster or what you pay for electricity.